# General Steiner Tree Variants

Tags: graphs, linear-programming

In the general Steiner tree problem (Steiner tree in graphs), we are given an edge-weighted graph G = (V, E, w) and a subset S ⊆ V of required vertices. A Steiner tree is a tree in G that spans all vertices of S. There are two versions of the problem: in the optimization problem associated with Steiner trees, the task is to find a minimum-weight Steiner tree.

This is an online compendium on approximability of the Steiner Tree and related optimization problems: http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/info5/steinerkompendium/

I am currently studying different Steiner tree variants on Graphs and i had already read Compendium but i haven't found the following cases.

1. INSTANCE: Graph  $G=(V,E)$ , unweighted edges ,given **a set** of terminals $S\subset V$.
   SOLUTION: A tree T=(${V_t},E_t$) in G such that $V_t$ number is minimum, $S\subset V_t\subset V, E_t\subset E$.

This problem looks like set cover problem or Vertex Cover for a specified subset of V. Also asked here: 
[Minimal Steiner Tree in unweighted directed graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56800/minimal-steiner-tree-in-unweighted-directed-graph)
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19477/steiner-tree-problem-for-unweighted-graphs for complexity only.
also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975763/minimum-connected-subgraph-containing-a-given-set-of-nodes/
and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056212/minimum-spanning-tree-between-a-start-location-and-a-set-of-required-nodes

2. INSTANCE: Graph  $G=(V,E)$ , edge weight->$\mathbb{R^+}$ , given **a set** of terminals $S\subset V$, node weight->R+. SOLUTION: A tree T=(${V_t},E_t$) in G such that T Prize(node **and** edge weights) is maximum and number of edges is minimum (Ratio:NodesWeights/NumberEdges) , $S\subset V_t\subset V, E_t\subset E$. (maximum path with minimum hopes-jumbs-edges).

This problem looks like Prize-Collecting Steiner Tree Problem.

3. INSTANCE: Graph  $G=(V,E)$ , edge weight->$\mathbb{R^+}$ , given **a number** for terminals $S\subset V$, where each S is adjacent to at least one other S, node weight->R+.
   SOLUTION: A tree T=(${V_t},E_t$) in G such that T Prize(node **and** edge weights) is maximum ,$S\subset V_t\subset V, E_t\subset E$.

I want to know if any of these cases can be transformed into already known cases or if they are already exists. Are all of them Np ?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "can be transformed into already known cases or if they are already exists"?  Is your real question: Are all of these problems in NP?  If so, you should probably be asking as 3 separate questions -- one question per question, please.  2. What is the definition of "$V_t$ number"?  3. What is the definition of "T Prize"?  What is meant by "Ratio:NodesWeights/NumberEdges"?  "hopes-jumbs-edges"?  4. Your problem #2 is not well-defined; we might not be able to simultaneously maximize one objective function and minimize another.

Comment: 1. For example if we split edge weight to start and end nodes than we have node weights only. etc . Maybe it can be with those problems. Furthermore i want to know if all of them variants of Stainer tree are in NP. 2. When i am writting $V_t$ number means the number of nodes of the steiner tree.

Comment: 3.  The Prize-Collecting Steiner Tree Problem (PCST) on a graph : http://www.siam.org/meetings/alenex05/papers/06iljubic.pdf .
- When i am writting Ratio:NodesWeights/NumberEdges . For example. points-nodes: a.weight=5 b.weight=4 c.weight=2 d.weight=2 . So if you have to paths that connects two terminals t1 and t2: path1: t1 -> a - > d-> t2 . path2: t1-> b-> c-> t2 . then the algorithm has to selects path1.

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one question per post.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!